# How did they get 2n + 10 here?

Tags: fractions

Daniel can encode a paper in $5$ hours and together he and Dennis can encode it in $2$ hours, how long would it take Dennis to encode the same paper alone?

> If Daniel can encode a paper in $5$ hours,
> then he encodes $\frac15$th paper per hour.
> Let $n$ be the time it takes Dennis to encode a paper.
> $$\frac{1}{5} +\frac{ 1}{n} = \frac{1}{2}$$
> $$2n + 10 = 5n$$
> $$10 = 3n$$
> $$n = \frac{10}{3}$$
> $$n = 3\dfrac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Since $n\neq 0$, have you tried to multiply both sides of the equation by 10n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They simply used ::$$\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{5+n}{5n}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$10+2n=5n\tag{basics of fraction addition}$$

Comment: Genius, thanks for the help. What do you call this process sir?

Comment: Uh, simply making the denominator same? and then adding. No name required

Comment: @AllanChua see this: https://www.mathsisfun.com/fractions_addition.html